# How to disable Azure API management cache

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am using the Azure API management developer version, here whenever I hit the GET method it fetches the data from the cache, not from the database, I need to fetch the data from the database, how to disable the cache, and configure it to fetch the data from only database not from the cache.

And I didn't configure the cache for my APIs, I have attached the snapshot for reference.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by tables?

Comment: What cache are using?

Comment: What policies are using in the operations?

Comment: I did not configure any API caching policies; I only configured the Cors policy.

Comment: Can you show us the policies of the APIs `CIS-dotnet-API` and `CIS-py-API`?

Comment: I didn't configure any policies in CIS-py-API and CIS-dotnet-API, and I have added a snapshot of the policies for reference.

Comment: I can see only a screenshot of `All APIs` policies. Where can I find the screenshots for the policies of `CIS-dotnet-API` and `CIS-py-API`

Comment: In the question section, the last one is the snapshot of CIS-py-API policies.

Comment: Are there any operations in the `CIS-py-API`? What is the content of the operation policies?

Comment: Yes, CIS-py-API is configured for CRUD operations, and the operation policies are empty since I didn't configure any operation policies there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AFAIK if you have any `cache-lookup` and `cache-store` policies from the inbound processing section of your API's policies then you can remove those policies by following below steps**.

- For sample purpose i have added `cache-lookup` policy in my API's inbound processing as shown in below image.
  [image]
- In the Azure portal, navigate to your API Management instance. Select the API and operation that you want to modify. Select the `Design` tab.
- Then In the `Inbound processing` section as shown in below image in `cache-lookup` click on **(...)** and then select **Delete** then save the changes. In this way you can delete.
  [image]
- `The other way` is go to Inbound processing and click on **policy code editor icon** beside policy then you can navigate to your inbound policy code view as shown in below image then select the `cache-lookup` policy there and simply remove and save.
  [image]
- By following any of the above mentioned 2 ways you can remove cache-lookup policy. After deleting you can see in below image there is no cache-lookup policy.
  [image]
  You can also refer this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/cache/delete?tabs=HTTP) for cache delete.

NOTE: caching can enhance your API's performance by decreasing the volume of queries made to the backend service. There is a chance that response times will be slower if caching is disabled. By tables, I assume you mean the backend data source that your API Management instance is connected to.

Comment: I did not configure any API caching policies; I only configured the Cors policy. However, since the response comes from the cache, is there a default cache for API management?

Comment: What is this "default" cache you're talking about?  I'm not aware of any APIM caching other than by enabling it through a policy.  If there are no API caching policies I would assume caching is occurring somewhere else, like the app itself or possibly a CDN?

Comment: @vijaya, Is there any way to disable it, or any way to configure it to get data from the database not from the cache?

Comment: caching is only enabled when you configure caching policies in your API's policies. AFAIK if You did not configure any caching policies, then it is possible that caching is occurring somewhere else, such as in your backend service or a CDN.